# I can't install Java JDK on my computer?

Tags: java, installation

I downloaded Java JDK 8 from Oracle website, but I can't install it. The problem is that the setup file doesn't open. There is no error message or something like that, the file just doesn't open. Could you please offer a solution?

Comment: Did you get the correct installer for your operating system? You will have to be more specific in how you encountered this problem, such as which installer you're using, and what your operating system is.

Comment: Did you download the proper installer?

Comment: if using windows try: reboot your system, then download the right setup.exe for your version 32/64Bit and try it again

Comment: My operating system is Windows and I downloaded Windows x64 installer

Comment: Perhaps your installed Anti_Virus software doesn't like it for some reason.